# Get up and down route between two stations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a city metro train app in laravel. I have a route search feature where the user can add two stations' source and destination, and the app should give the appropriate route between two stations.

My table structure is as below. I am getting a route between stations by defining `route_id`. However, the user won't know which route id and only two stations s/he want to get the route.

With this approach, I have to define the route_id to get the route using a recursive query.

> ##### Looking for solution:
>
> So here I want to find a way so I can get a route between the same two stations for up and down. For instance, Get a
> route from station_id 1 to 8 and from station_id 8 to 1 without
> getting route_id as user input.

### Laravel migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create(
        'route_station',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('route_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('station_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('next_station_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('station_order')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('interchange_id')->unsigned();
            $table->float('distance');
            $table->time('duration');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['route_id', 'station_id'], 'route_station_unique');

            $table->foreign('route_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('routes')
                  ->onDelete('restrict');

            $table->foreign('station_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('stations')
                  ->onDelete('restrict');

            $table->foreign('next_station_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('stations')
                  ->onDelete('restrict');

            $table->foreign('interchange_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('stations')
                  ->onDelete('restrict');

        }
    );
}
```

### Database

```
+----+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+
| id | route_id | station_id | next_station_id | station_order | interchange_id | distance | duration |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+
|  1 |        2 |          1 |               2 |             1 |           NULL |      2.1 |      510 |
|  2 |        2 |          2 |               3 |             2 |           NULL |      1.3 |      250 |
|  3 |        2 |          3 |               4 |             3 |           NULL |      3.2 |      380 |
|  4 |        2 |          4 |               5 |             4 |           NULL |      4.5 |      725 |
|  5 |        2 |          5 |               6 |             5 |           NULL |        2 |      200 |
|  6 |        2 |          6 |               7 |             6 |           NULL |      2.7 |      270 |
|  7 |        2 |          7 |               8 |             7 |           NULL |      1.3 |      320 |
|  8 |        2 |          8 |               9 |             8 |              9 |      0.5 |      120 |
|  9 |        2 |          9 |            NULL |             9 |           NULL |      1.9 |      510 |
| 27 |        3 |          8 |               7 |             8 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 28 |        3 |          7 |               6 |             7 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 29 |        3 |          6 |               5 |             6 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 30 |        3 |          5 |               4 |             5 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 31 |        3 |          4 |               3 |             4 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 32 |        3 |          3 |               2 |             3 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 33 |        3 |          2 |               1 |             2 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
| 34 |        3 |          1 |            NULL |             1 |           NULL |        2 |      111 |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+
```

### Query

```
SET @source = 1, @route_id = 2, @destination = 8;

WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS 
(
    SELECT `route_id`, `station_id`, `next_station_id`, `station_order`
    FROM `route_stations`
    WHERE `station_id` = @source
    AND `route_id` = @route_id
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT cte.`route_id`, cte.`next_station_id`, `route_stations`.`next_station_id`, cte.`station_order` + 1
    FROM `route_stations`, cte
    WHERE `route_stations`.`station_id` = cte.`next_station_id`
        AND cte.`next_station_id` != @source
        AND cte.`station_id` != @destination
        AND `route_stations`.`route_id` = @route_id
    
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE @destination = (SELECT `station_id` FROM cte ORDER BY `station_order` DESC LIMIT 1);
```

### Output looking for

##### From station_id 2 to 8

If the user search source station_id 2 and destination station_id to 8

[image]

##### From station_id 8 to 2

If the user search source station_id 8 and destination station_id to 2

[image]

> I am open to database changes so feel free to advise me if any way to
> make a better database structure.

Comment: Provide your table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Provide desired result for this data and provided condition(s).

Comment: I am using laravel to create a table. Insert query is in progress as I need to finalize the structure to retrieve the route. I will post laravel migration.

Comment: @Akina, I have added the info you requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare  @source int, @destination int, @route_id int
set @source = 2
set @destination = 8
set @route_id= case when @source<@destination then 2 else 3 end
select route_id,station_id,next_station_id,station_order from route_station where route_id = @route_id and station_id between @source and @destination and next_station_id between @source and @destination

select route_id,station_id,next_station_id,station_order from route_station where route_id = @route_id and station_id between @destination and @source and next_station_id between @destination and @source
```

I hope you will understand this sql code.
Here if source id is lass then destination id the route_id set 2
otherwise 3.

here 2 select query.

this solution is easy when you use sql table value function.